# Pygame how do I create duplicates of a sprite class then put them in a group?

Tags: python, class, random, pygame, sprite

Hello I'm trying to randomly spawn copies of my Pipes class then display them to the screen. I set up a random number generator that has a 1/3 chance to get a 1. If it gets a 1 I made another random number generator to choose a number betweeen 0 and 600(the width of my screen) to be the x coordinate of the new sprite. Then I display that sprite to the screen using the random x coordinate and a predefined y coordinate.

```
            class Pipes(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self, x):
                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                            self.imx = 0
                            self.imgy = 375
                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()

                    def playerRect(self):
                            self.x = self.imgx
                            self.y = self.imgy
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

                    def draw(self):
                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                    def update(self):
                        self.spawn = random.randint(0, 3)
                        if self.spawn == 1:
                            self.spawnx = random.randint(0, 600)
                            setDisplay.blit(self.img, [self.spawnx, 375])
                            allPipes.add(new_instance(self.spawnx))
```

Then I made a group of sprites called allPipes that will hold the new instances of Pipe and make a constructor for Pipe.

```
            allPipes = pygame.sprite.Group()
            pipe = Pipes(0)
```

Then in my gameloop I called the Pipes draw function which randomly spawns the new instances and draw and update the allPipes group but the images for the sprite appear on the screen but then dissapear when the new one appears which makes me believe that its not actually making a new instance of Pipes each time. Can somone please help?

```
            def gameLoop():



                imgx = 10
                imgy = 10
                lead_x_change = 0
                lead_y_change = 0
                move_variable = 100
                jumpcounter = 0


                while True:





                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        #print (event)

                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()


                        elif event.type == timer_event:
                                trail
                                allPipes = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(())
                                player.playerRect()
                                #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(background.img2, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(player.img, [player.imgx, player.imgy])
                                #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(ground.img, [ground.imgx, ground.imgy])
                                pipe.update()
                                allPipes.draw(setDisplay)
                                for sprite in allPipes:
                                sprite.update()
```

This is the full code:

```
            import pygame
            import sys
            from pygame.locals import *
            import random
            #creates a clock to count framerate
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            #starts the program
            pygame.init()
            isFalling = True
            allPipes = pygame.sprite.Group()

            #creates a window of 800x600
            setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
            pygame.display.set_caption('Menu')
            #loads image for sprite
            img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png')
            allPipes = pygame.sprite.Group()

            #player class
            class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self):
                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                            self.imgx = 0
                            self.imgy = 375
                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()

                    def playerRect(self):
                            self.x = self.imgx
                            self.y = self.imgy
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

                    def draw(self):
                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)

                    def load(self, filename):
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()               


            class Trail(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self):
                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                            self.x = player.imgx - 1
                            self.y = player.imgy - 1
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 10))

                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()
                    def trailrect(self):
                            self.x = player.imgx - 1
                            self.y = player.imgy - 1
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 10))
                    def draw(self):
                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                            trail.trailrect()


            class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self):
                             pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                             self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert()
                             self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert()
                             self.treesx = 0
                             self.treesy = 70
                             self.treesrect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),pygame.Rect(self.treesx, self.treesy, 376, 100))
                    def draw(self):
                             self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                             self.setDisplay.blit(self.img2)

                    def load(self, filename):
                             self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert_alpha()
                             self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert_alpha()
            class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self):
                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\ground.png').convert()
                            self.imgx = 0
                            self.imgy = 400
                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()
                            self.x = self.imgx
                            self.y = self.imgy
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 800, 200))

                    def draw(self):
                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)

                    def load(self, filename):
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()               
            class Pipes(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                    def __init__(self, x):
                            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                            self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                            self.imx = 0
                            self.imgy = 375
                            self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()

                    def playerRect(self):
                            self.x = self.imgx
                            self.y = self.imgy
                            self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

                    def draw(self):
                            self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                    def update(self):
                        self.spawn = random.randint(0, 3)
                        if self.spawn == 1:
                            self.spawnx = random.randint(0, 600)
                            setDisplay.blit(self.img, [self.spawnx, 375])
                            allPipes.add(new_instance(self.spawnx))

            player = Player()              
            background = Background()
            ground = Ground()
            trail = Trail()
            timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
            pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, 250)
            trail.trailrect()
            pipe = Pipes(0)
            def gameLoop():



                imgx = 10
                imgy = 10
                lead_x_change = 0
                lead_y_change = 0
                move_variable = 100
                jumpcounter = 0


                while True:





                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        #print (event)

                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()


                        elif event.type == timer_event:
                                trail
                                allPipes = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(())
                                player.playerRect()
                                #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(background.img2, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(player.img, [player.imgx, player.imgy])
                                #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                                setDisplay.blit(ground.img, [ground.imgx, ground.imgy])
                                pipe.update()
                                allPipes.draw(setDisplay)
                                for sprite in allPipes:
                                sprite.update()






                                #rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 32, 32))
                                player.imgy += 30


                                isFalling = False
                                groundColliding = False
                                if isFalling == True:
                                        player.imgy += 0

                                if player.rect.colliderect(ground.rect):
                                                print("collided")
                                                isFalling = False
                                                groundColliding = True
                                                player.imgy = 370
                                                jumpcounter = 0











                                if player.rect.colliderect(background.treesrect):
                                        print("c")



                                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                                if keys[K_LEFT]:
                                    player.imgx -= 20
                                if keys[K_RIGHT]:
                                    player.imgx += 20
                                if keys[K_UP]:
                                    if jumpcounter < 2:
                                            player.imgy -= 50
                                            isFalling = True
                                            jumpcounter += 1








                                print(player.x, player.y)
                                print (isFalling, groundColliding)
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    #pygame.display.update()
                    clock.tick(70)

            gameLoop()
            #start (0, 71)
            #length (376, 71)
            #width (0, 168)
```

Comment: Please verify that the indentation in your Code is correct and remove all those leading white space in your code to make it more readable. If the code here is exactly like your code than have a look at: `for sprite in allPipes:` the line after this is not executed in the loop as it is not indented.

Comment: In the update method for the Pipes you add `new_instance(self.spanx)` but  I don't think you actually define new_instance anywhere

Answer (score 0):

there were a lot of indentation error.
try this:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
#creates a clock to count framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#starts the program
pygame.init()
isFalling = True
allPipes = pygame.sprite.Group()

#creates a window of 800x600
setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Menu')
#loads image for sprite
img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png')
allPipes = pygame.sprite.Group()

#player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                self.imgx = 0
                self.imgy = 375
                self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()

        def playerRect(self):
                self.x = self.imgx
                self.y = self.imgy
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

        def draw(self):
                self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)

        def load(self, filename):
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()               


class Trail(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.x = player.imgx - 1
                self.y = player.imgy - 1
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 10))

                self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()
        def trailrect(self):
                self.x = player.imgx - 1
                self.y = player.imgy - 1
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 10))
        def draw(self):
                self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                trail.trailrect()


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                 pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                 self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert()
                 self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert()
                 self.treesx = 0
                 self.treesy = 70
                 self.treesrect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255),pygame.Rect(self.treesx, self.treesy, 376, 100))
        def draw(self):
                 self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
                 self.setDisplay.blit(self.img2)

        def load(self, filename):
                 self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\background.png').convert_alpha()
                 self.img2 = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\trees1.png').convert_alpha()
class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\ground.png').convert()
                self.imgx = 0
                self.imgy = 400
                self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()
                self.x = self.imgx
                self.y = self.imgy
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 800, 200))

        def draw(self):
                self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)

        def load(self, filename):
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert_alpha()               
class Pipes(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.img = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\sprite.png').convert()
                self.imx = 0
                self.imgy = 375
                self.setDisplay = pygame.display.get_surface()

        def playerRect(self):
                self.x = self.imgx
                self.y = self.imgy
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

        def draw(self):
                self.setDisplay.blit(self.img)
        def update(self):
            self.spawn = random.randint(0, 3)
            if self.spawn == 1:
                self.spawnx = random.randint(0, 600)
                setDisplay.blit(self.img, [self.spawnx, 375])
                allPipes.add(new_instance(self.spawnx))

player = Player()              
background = Background()
ground = Ground()
trail = Trail()
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, 250)
trail.trailrect()
pipe = Pipes(0)
def gameLoop():



    imgx = 10
    imgy = 10
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    move_variable = 100
    jumpcounter = 0


    while True:





        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print (event)

            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


            elif event.type == timer_event:
                    trail
                    allPipes = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(())
                    player.playerRect()
                    #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                    setDisplay.blit(background.img2, [0, 0])
                    setDisplay.blit(player.img, [player.imgx, player.imgy])
                    #setDisplay.blit(background.img, [0, 0])
                    setDisplay.blit(ground.img, [ground.imgx, ground.imgy])
                    pipe.update()
                    allPipes.draw(setDisplay)
                    for sprite in allPipes:
                        sprite.update()






                    #rect = pygame.draw.rect(setDisplay, pygame.Color(0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 32, 32))
                    player.imgy += 30


                    isFalling = False
                    groundColliding = False
                    if isFalling == True:
                            player.imgy += 0

                    if player.rect.colliderect(ground.rect):
                                    print("collided")
                                    isFalling = False
                                    groundColliding = True
                                    player.imgy = 370
                                    jumpcounter = 0











                    if player.rect.colliderect(background.treesrect):
                            print("c")



                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[K_LEFT]:
                        player.imgx -= 20
                    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
                        player.imgx += 20
                    if keys[K_UP]:
                        if jumpcounter < 2:
                                player.imgy -= 50
                                isFalling = True
                                jumpcounter += 1








                    print(player.x, player.y)
                    print (isFalling, groundColliding)
        pygame.display.flip()
        #pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(70)

gameLoop()
#start (0, 71)
#length (376, 71)
#width (0, 168)
```